# How did a tropical storm starting with "D" end up next to a typhoon starting with "T"?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

While keeping a close eye on typhoon Talim, I noticed that tropical storm Doksuri is also on the map and has caused serious damage and loss of life. I had thought that the naming of tropical storms is alphabetical (within a given area) so it seems that Doksuri with a "D" must be quite old by now, and Talim fairly young.

Do I have the basic idea correct? I've tried to read the Wikipedia article [Tropical cyclone naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone_naming#Eastern_Pacific_Ocean) but it gets a little complicated to read as it start to break things down by East Pacific and West Pacific and I am not sure from where these two originated.

How did a "D" and a "T" end up so close together? Is this unusual?

**below:** Screen shot from the Taiwan Central Weather Bureau's [Typhoon News](http://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7e/prevent/typhoon/ty.htm?) page.

[image: Typhoon Talim and Tropical Storm Doksuri]

Comment: @Communisty Thanks, but that edit subverts my question, both by making it hemisphere-agnostic and by glossing over the issue of non-alpabeticalicity.

Comment: I still think that the current title isn't very informative description of the actual question. It gives insight only to those who think typhoons are named in an alphabetic order...

Comment: @Communisty and yet, that is my question to a "T" :-) Can you suggest a better title that includes my preconception that name should be alphabetical (as they are in some places but not in others) and that would not conflict with the existing answer which focuses specifically on *typhoon Talim and tropical storm Doksuri*? The question and answer have happened they way they did, and we can't go back in time and wish that another question was asked and another answer was written.

Comment: @Communisty I've been thinking about this more and was considering asking a second, more generalized question along the lines that you proposed. I went and looked at the Wikipedia article [Tropical Cyclone Naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone_naming) and there are eight distinct regions, each with it's own naming system. A general answer would have to be huge and essential replicate the article. It looks like there's no easy way to make this general in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naming of typhoons, in the north west pacific region, is different to that used by other parts of the world. According to [accuweather](https://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-news/typhoons-how-are-they-named-pacific/32987163),

> For typhoons, there is one list with 140 names submitted from nations in the region such as China, Japan, Vietnam and Cambodia. There is no restrictions to how many can be used in a calendar year.
>
> “Unlike hurricanes, lists are not year-specific, so they scroll through the whole list irrespective of calendar
>
> The Philippines are also a part of the list of nations which submit names. However, according to the Philippine Atmospheric, Geophysical and Astronomical Services Administration (PAGASA), they will use local names whenever a cyclone is within the Philippine Area of Responsibility (PAR).

[NOAA](http://www.prh.noaa.gov/cphc/pages/names.php) has a list of the names for the north west pacific region. At the end of the webpage, in column V of the last table you will see Talim followed by Doksuri, then Khanun. This is why you are seeing Tropical Storm Doksuri just after Tropical Storm Talim.

[image]

It appears that [Doksuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Storm_Doksuri), which means eagle, Korean, is the replacement name for Nabi. South Korea submitted the name Nabli to the list of typhoon names, but the name Nabi was retired when Typhoon Nabi hit Japan in 2005.

Tropical Storm Doksuri (2017) was initially named [Maring](https://pubfiles.pagasa.dost.gov.ph/tamss/weather/bulletin2.pdf) by the Philippine authorities.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you for taking the time to put together a thorough answer. You could have just as easily said "They're not alphabetical" in a comment. Now the Wikipedia page and other pages (including the bulletin from the Philippines) are all making more sense to me.